# Jquery auto-fading

Tags: jquery, ajax, fade

I have some elements pushed on the page via ajax. How can I make them disapear 3 seconds after their creation, for exemple with a fade-out effect ?

The html is pushed by an external jQuery library performing multiple upload ( http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ ). After a file is uploaded, the plugin pulls this on the page:

```
<div class="template-download fade">
    FileName ...
    Errors...
</div>
```

Comment: can we see some code on how and what elements are you pushing to the page? A simple `setTimeout(function(){ $("#pushedDiv").fadeOut(); }, 3000);` after you `append` the elements will always do the trick...

Comment: For exemple a simple div like this : <div class"fade">yeah</div>.
Ok for the solution with setTimeout, but it won't be too memory hungry ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the plugin's callback functions. For instance:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {
    setTimeout(function(){$('div.template-download.fade').fadeOut()}, 3000);
});
```

...should trigger a fadeOut on the element 3000 milliseconds after your AJAX return, regardless of what the result was.

Callbacks are essential to any kind of AJAX functionality. Normally your code keeps on running as quickly as possible, without waiting for your AJAX function or method to return any data. The callback is only run after it returns a result, and specific callbacks can be called for specific results.

Other callbacks exist only for successful uploads, failed uploads, etc. Read https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options and scroll down to "callback options."

Comment: I can't access to the callback becase the Ajax call is performed by a plugin.

Comment: This doesn't work, here is my code : setTimeout(function(){$('.fade').fadeOut()}, 3000);
I put it outside any load/ajax call.

Comment: @YvanL. If you can't access the callback, then you're probably stuck. There might be solutions, but without your code we have no idea what to suggest. Please post some actual code if you want more specific suggestions.

Comment: The elements come from a multiple upload script, it pushes a status for each uploaded file like this : <div class="template-download fade">...Some status messages...</div>. This code is generated by the plugin itselft.

Comment: @YvanL.Let me rephrase: please *update your original question* with some specific sample code. Adding a link to a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be even better.

Comment: @YvanL. Updated my answer. See? Good things happen when you provide the actual code (and plugins) you're using!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").html("example example").delay(3000).fadeOut();​
```

this is why we are using jquery.

**EDIT for @mblase75 comment,**

```
$("div").load('ajax.html').delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: OP said he was using AJAX to load the new content.

Comment: @mblase75, I just write method, nothing changes in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This should go

```
setTimeout(fadeout(),3000);

function fadeout(){

$("yourid").fadeOut();

}
```

Comment: The syntax of the setTimeout method should be : setTimeout("fadeout()",3000);  BTW, this doesn't work for me ;)